# Why I am no able to adjust my ASUS laptop screen brightness?

Tags: grub2, asus, brightness

I found many problem in my screen brightness regulation.

My laptop model is ASUS VivoBook pro 15 N580GD-DM041T and I installed Ubuntu 19.10 on it.

I already tried to change the grub configuration using:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

And I changed the line `GRUN_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=! acpi_backlight=vendor idle=nomwait quiet splash nomodeset"
```

But I didn't get results. Does anyone have any ideas about it?

Comment: this gnome tweak on 19.10 gives me 15 levels of brightness....https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1410/discrete-brightness/

Comment: Thank you @pierrely but it looks like it doesn't work. I downloaded the zip file from github, extracted it and I runned the makefile from terminal but nothing is changed.

Comment: -1
ooops 
@tanzobar . there are other tweaks for contrast there too. I install them through firefox. perhaps different shades of semi transparent film over the monitor? (/joking)